# Getting error in build by gradle Unknown host 'You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am new to gradle.I am getting error
Unknown host 'This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (xyz.com)'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

How , what proxy settings and where we need to put these settings in Intellij?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot with the message you get?

Comment: Is it an Android project?

Comment: no it is microservices spring boot project

Comment: Add  a screenshot with the message you get.